# Why a lot of lapack functions are missing from scipy interface

Tags: python, scipy, lapack

In [lapack](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/index.html) there are much more functions than in ["lapack interface" in scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.lapack.html#module-scipy.linalg.lapack). Is there any reason behind this and is there OS-independentway to call lapack functions directly?

I realize that I may call dinamic library directly, but this means writing my own wrapper and this is not what I want.

To make a real usecase, I need to call [dsbgv](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dc/dd2/group__double_o_t_h_e_reigen_ga2153e07720577f4ee935f96f960aa42e.html#ga2153e07720577f4ee935f96f960aa42e) to solve generalized eigenproblem for banded matrix. It is orders of magnitude faster than using eig which is for general matrix.

Comment: There's a longer list on https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.cython_lapack.html

Answer (score 1):

`scipy.linalg.lapack` is an organically grown (tm) set of wrappers, added by different people with different goals, needs, motivations and time budgets over quite a few years.

`cython_lapack` is a complete set of wrappers for a certain (old enough) version of LAPACK. It is lower level however: you need to supply all lapack arguments, ensure the correct array ordering, alignment etc.